# SQL : how to query only 1 time instead of loop over dates?

Tags: sql, mybatis, ibatis

I have a table like this :

```
---------------------------------------
product_id | valid_from  | valid_till |
1          |  2018-01-01 | 2018-09-01 |
2          |  2013-03-01 | 2019-07-01 |
---------------------------------------
```

...

I want to retrieve **all valid products for a list of given dates**, and put them into a `map<Date, List<Product>>` :

so what I do is :

```
Map<Date, List<Product>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Date date : list_date) {
    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("date", date);
    List<Product> products = this.queryForList("getProductForDate", param);
    map.put(date, products);
}
```

and my query is :

```
select product_id
from my_table
where date >= valid_from and date < valid_till
```

but I want to know, is it possible to do the query **1 time only** instead of loop on dates in the code ? How to deal with the where clause in this case ?

Comment: What is the expected output? Is your query not working?

Comment: what DB are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using Oracle, I don't know what the expected output in oracle should be but in mybatis it should return a map<Date, List<Product>>

Comment: @google_tech_lead Are dates in the `list_date` random or something like 'every day in a month'?

Comment: hi it's random dates

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE may be the simplest solution.

You can pass the list of date as a parameter.

```java
Map<Date, List<Product>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
param.put("dates", list_date);
List<Map<String, ?>> result = this.queryForList("getProductForDate", param);
```

The statement and the result map may look as follows:

```xml
<select id="getValidProductsInternal" resultMap="productsPerDate">
  with dates(d) as (
    <foreach item="date" collection="dates" separator="union all">
      select #{date,jdbcType=DATE} as d from dual
    </foreach>
  )
  select dates.d date_in_question, t.product_id
  from dates
  left join my_table t on
    dates.d >= t.valid_from and t.valid_till > dates.d
</select>

<resultMap type="map" id="productsPerDate">
  <id column="date_in_question" property="date" />
  <collection property="products" javaType="list"
      ofType="test.Product">
    <id column="product_id" property="id" />
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Explaining CTE may be off-topic, but simply put, the `with` clause build a virtual table (sort-of) `dates` with a single column `d` of type `DATE`.
It creates a row for each `Date` in the `dates` parameter, so if you pass three `Date`s as the parameter, there will be three rows in the `dates` table.
The `select ... left join` part may be straightforward.

Now, the result may contain every date in the list even if there is no valid product for the date.
For example...

```
[
  {
    date : 2019-01-01,
    products : [
     {id: 2, ...}
    ]
  },
  {
    date : 2019-01-03,
    products : [
      {id: 1, ...},
      {id: 2, ...}
    ]
  },
  {
    date : 2019-01-05,
    products : []
  },
  ...
]
```

Although this result is not exactly what you want, it is easy to convert.

```java
Map<Date, List<Product>> validProductsPerDate = result.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    e -> (Date) e.get("date"),
    e -> (List<Product>) e.get("products")));
```

Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-58727455).
The demo uses mapper interface and includes both examples of random and sequential dates.

Answer (score -1):

I know Mybatis has selectMap method in SqlSession interface， But I have never used it，You can try it yourself.I believe it can.